# Openpyxl, Pandas or both

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, openpyxl

I'm trying to process an excel file so that i can use each row and column for specific operations later on.

My problem is as follows:

- Using Openpyxl made it easier for me to load the file and be able to iterate over the rows

```
    #reading the excel file
    path = r'Datasets/Chapter 1/Table B1.1.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(path) #loading the excel table
    ws = wb.active #grab the active worksheet
    
    #Setting the doc Header
    for h in ws.iter_rows(max_row = 1, values_only = True): #getting the first row (Headers) in the table
        header = list(h)
    
    for sh in ws.iter_rows(min_row = 1 ,max_row = 2, values_only = True):
        sub_header = list(sh)
    
    #removing all of the none Values
    header = list(filter(None, header))
    sub_header = list(filter(None, sub_header))
    #creating a list of all the rows in the excel file
    row_list = []
    
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3): #Iteration over every single row starting from the third row since first two are the headers
        row = [cell.value for cell in row] #Creating a list from each row
        row = list(filter(None, row)) #removing the none values from each row
        row_list.append(row) #creating a list of all rows (starting from the 3d one)

    colm = []
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=3,min_col = 1): #Iteration over every single row starting from the third row since first two are the headers
        col = [cell.value for cell in col] #Creating a list from each row
        col = list(filter(None, col)) #removing the none values from each row
        colm.append(col) #creating a list of all rows (starting from the 3d one)
```

but at the same time (as far as I've read in the docs), I can't visualize it or do direct operations on the rows or columns.

- While using pandas is more efficient to do direct operations on the rows and columns, I've read that iterating over a dataframe to get the rows in a list is not recommended even if it were to be done using `df.iloc[2:]` it would not give me the same result (saving each row in a specific list since the headers would always be there). However, unlike Openpyxl, doing direct operations on columns is much easier using something like `df[col1]-df[col2]` using the column name which is something I need to do. (Since just putting all columns values in a list wont do it for me)

So my question is whether or not there is a solution to be able to do what I want using only one of them, or if using both of them isn't that bad, keeping in mind I'd have to load the excel file twice.

"Thanks in Advance!"

Comment: It is not clear what your code is trying to do. Are you using this to collect "Non-Falsy" or `not None` values from the spreadsheet into `row_list` and `colm`? If your concern is that your two `for loops` will be slower in `pandas`, you have an option of setting `engine='openpyxl'` in the `pd.read_excel(...` function

Comment: It would be best to provide some sample input that we can copy-paste into an Excel, the expected output and any performance / timing metrics you might have.

Comment: Please ask questions rating to specific problems. Speculating about libraries is, unfortunately, a waste of time for all concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem to read an excel file once using openpyxl and then load rows to pandas:

```py
pandas.DataFrame(row_list, columns=header)
```

You are right, iterating over a `DataFrame` using indexes is quite slow, but you have other options: [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), [`itertuples()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html)

Link: [Different ways to iterate over rows in pandas DataFrame](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/)

I would also like to point out that your code probably does not do what you would like.

1. `list(filter(None, header))` filters not only None, but all falsy-values such as `0` or `""`.
2. such filtering shifts the columns. for example, you have a row `[1, None, 3]` and columns `['a', 'b', 'c']`. by filtering None, you will get `[1, 3]` which will relate to columns `'a'` and `'b'`.